# "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying to add coordinates to an array

Tags: arcpy, csv, cursor

I am trying to reconstruct a car's path from some GPS coordinates given in a CSV file. I created an empty array to add the X and Y values (lat, long) and create the lines using it but I am getting an `IndexError: list index out of range` for the `lat= line[latIndex]` part.

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I am still fairly new to Python and coding so bear with me here please. Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import csv

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\data"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput= True
FilePath= open(arcpy.env.workspace + "\GPSTrack.csv", "r")
shapefile_line= "carPathLine.shp"
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(arcpy.env.workspace, shapefile_line, "POLYLINE")

spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(shapefile_line).spatialReference

csvReader = csv.reader(FilePath)
headerLine= next(csvReader)

with FilePath as pointFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(pointFile)
    header= next(csvReader)

    latitude_Index= header.index("Latitude")
    longitude_Index = header.index("Longitude")

    coord_pairs= arcpy.Array()

    for coord in csvReader:
        lat= coord[latitude_Index]
        lon= coord[longitude_Index]

        coord_list= arcpy.Point(lon,lat)
        coord_pairs.add(coord_list)

    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(shapefile_line, ("SHAPE@")) as cursor:
        # Create a Polyline from your Array
        car_polyline = arcpy.Polyline(coord_pairs, spatialRef)
        cursor.insertRow((car_polyline,))

print("success!")
```

Here is a sample of the CSV file:

[image]

```
Time    Lap GPS_Update  GPS_Delay   Accuracy (m)    Latitude    Longitude   Altitude (m)    Speed (KM/H)    Heading Accel X Accel Y Accel Z
0   0   1   0   13  -34.8394436 149.6849218 672 0   0   0   0   0
0.012   0   0   0   13  -34.8394436 149.6849218 672 0   0   0   0   0
0.113   0   0   0   13  -34.8394436 149.6849218 672 0   0   0   0   0
0.113   0   1   0   13  -34.8394436 149.6849218 672 0   0   0   0   0
100.051 0   1   0   3   -34.8401262 149.6844768 670 22.1    199.5   0.01    -0.01   -0.01
100.11  0   0   0   3   -34.8401262 149.6844768 670 22.1    199.5   0.03    0   0.01
100.172 0   0   0   3   -34.8401262 149.6844768 670 22.1    199.5   0.04    0.01    0.02
100.231 0   0   0   3   -34.8401262 149.6844768 670 22.1    199.5   0.03    0.01    0.01
100.293 0   0   0   3   -34.8401262 149.6844768 670 22.1    199.5   0.02    0   -0.01
100.355 0   0   0   3   -34.8401262 149.6844768 670 22.1    199.5   0.02    -0.01   -0.01
100.415 0   0   0   3   -34.8401262 149.6844768 670 22.1    199.5   0.02    -0.01   0
100.476 0   0   0   3   -34.8401262 149.6844768 670 22.1    199.5   0.04    -0.01   0.01
100.534 0   0   0   3   -34.8401262 149.6844768 670 22.1    199.5   0.04    0   0.01
456.775 3   0   0   3   -34.8434759 149.6846522 680 51.2    240.2   -0.08   -0.48   -0.01
456.835 3   0   0   3   -34.8434759 149.6846522 680 51.2    240.2   -0.1    -0.46   -0.02
456.896 3   0   0   3   -34.8434759 149.6846522 680 51.2    240.2   -0.13   -0.46   -0.02
456.957 3   0   0   3   -34.8434759 149.6846522 680 51.2    240.2   -0.15   -0.45   0
457.016 3   0   0   3   -34.8434759 149.6846522 680 51.2    240.2   -0.14   -0.46   0
457.055 3   1   0   3   -34.8435081 149.6845147 680 43.2    260.5   -0.16   -0.46   0
457.118 3   0   0   3   -34.8435081 149.6845147 680 43.2    260.5   -0.17   -0.46   -0.01
457.179 3   0   0   3   -34.8435081 149.6845147 680 43.2    260.5   -0.19   -0.47   -0.01
457.237 3   0   0   3   -34.8435081 149.6845147 680 43.2    260.5   -0.2    -0.48   0
457.283 3   0   0   3   -34.8435081 149.6845147 680 43.2    260.5   -0.21   -0.48   -0.01
457.338 3   0   0   3   -34.8435081 149.6845147 680 43.2    260.5   -0.21   -0.48   -0.01
457.4   3   0   0   3   -34.8435081 149.6845147 680 43.2    260.5   -0.23   -0.5    -0.02
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of the csv file as text? Which ArcGIS version do you have, Pro?

Comment: I am using the ArcGIS Pro! I will add a sample in my question

Comment: `long` is an *awful* name for a variable, since it's the name of a datatype (albeit not in Python 3); I recommend using `lon` or `lon_dd`. Always remember that longitude is the X value, and latitude the Y, so coordinates should be loaded via `arcpy.Point(lon,lat)`

Comment: @Vince, thank you for the suggestion, I have updated my question to reflect this.